# Why MVC3 return view without pass model can get validation error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I am reading the Pro Asp.Net MVC3 Framework and have a confused problem,it is not big, but I think it must have something deep inside can learn. The very simple code

```
public class AppointmentController : Controller
{
    private IAppointmentRepository repository;

    public AppointmentController(IAppointmentRepository repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public ViewResult MakeBooking()
    {
        return View(new Appointment {Date = DateTime.Now});
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult MakeBooking(Appointment appt)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appt.ClientName))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("ClientName", "Please enter your name");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValidField("Date") && DateTime.Now > appt.Date)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Date", "Please enter a date in the future");
        }

        if (!appt.TermsAccepted)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("TermsAccepted", "You must accept the terms");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValidField("ClientName") && ModelState.IsValidField("Date")
            && appt.ClientName == "Joe" && appt.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Joe cannot book appointments on Mondays");
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            repository.SaveAppointment(appt);
            return View("Completed", appt);
        }
        **else
        {
            return View();
        }**
    }
}
```

So my problem is: `ModelState` is not valid and return to a view to show the error, why use return `View()`, but not return `View(appt)`?

I have debug the code,it works,it means `@Html.ValidationSummary()` can show the error, and `Your name: @Html.EditorFor(m => m.ClientName)` will also show the `ClientName` in the input box.But if I want to use `@Model`, it is Null.
Why return `View()` without the model can hold the error and values in `EditorFor` html helper?

Comment: Justin's answer is correct, but it's unclear to me exactly what you're asking.  If you mean why you should or shouldn't pass the model, well in most cases you should pass the model as well.  The only reason you wouldn't is if you don't need the model in your view because everything you need is in the ModelState.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Microsoft employee actually explained this well on [his MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx):

> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an
>   HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely
>   to be redisplaying a form that has failed validation. Therefore, the
>   Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in
>   a field before they look in the Model. This enables them to redisplay
>   erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error
>   message if needed.

When `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ClientName)` is called it's actually looking inside the model state for a value that was previously sent instead of looking at the object model passed to the view.  It will look at the object model passed if there is no value in the model state.

If you want to verify this, simply call:

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

in your `HttpPost` action.  The value of the field will become whatever the value of the property was on the object passed to the view.  In your case you won't get a value since you're not returning an object to your view.

Comment: Thanks!I will look into detail from the MVC3 source code to understand it.But your answer really helps me a lot, I have searched 50 times in bing google Msdn but get nothing useful